# why my async await is not working properly

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

i am working on api with express js, in my api call i called 2 functions, first is `login()` and other function is `get_organizations()`, but `get_organization()` called without complete of `login()` function, i have used async await but it is not working properly, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ? I have added my whole code here ,

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let token = await login();
    await get_organizations(token);
});

const get_organizations = async function (api_token) {
    try {
        console.log('Get List Of Organizations');
        console.log('Verifying token');
        let verify_token_data = await jwt.verify(api_token, config['token-secret']);
        console.log(verify_token_data);
        return false;      
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const login = async function () {
    try {
        console.log('Login process started');
        const newToken = await jwt.sign({login:'login'},config['token-secret'],{ expiresIn: config['token-expires']});
        let username = 'root_admin'
        let password = 'Admin123';
        let token = String(cryptojs.lib.WordArray.random(20));
        console.log("token : "+token);
        await connection.query('SELECT * FROM users where username = ?  ',[username], async function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Looged out failed");
            } else {
                const user = rows[0];
                console.log("psdsdsd");
                if(bcrypt.compareSync(password,user.passwordHash)) {
                    await connection.query('SELECT * FROM organizations where id = ?  ',[user.organizationId], async function(err, org_data) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Looged out failed");
                        } else {
                            console.log("sdsd");
                            //console.log(org_data);
                            if(typeof org_data.name!='undefined') {
                                organization = org_data.name;
                            } else {
                                organization = 'VeriCurious';
                            }
                            //console.log(organization);
                            // create a token
                            const token = await jwt.sign({ id: user.id, username: user.username, organizationId: user.organizationId, organization: organization}, config['token-secret'], {
                                expiresIn: config['token-expires'] // expires in 30 minutes
                            }); 
                            console.log("Successfull loggedin");
                            console.log("New generated token : "+token);
                            return token;
                        }
                    });    
                }
            }    
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would appear `connetion.query` does not return a promise. You need to research how to convert callback's to Promises if you wish to await them. `async / await` is built on top of promises.

Comment: use node.js built-in 'util.promisify' method to convert callbacks to Promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `await` when invoking a function, you're basically waiting for a promise inside that function to resolve. The invoked function **is intended to return that promise**.

In your code, the `login` function does invoke `connection.query`, but there isn't any promise that waits for the query to resolve.

In order to get `await` to really wait for `connection.query`, you need to return a Promise which resolves whenever the user finally logs in - i.e. you have the token:

```
const login = async function () {
  try {
    console.log('Login process started');
    const newToken = await jwt.sign({login:'login'},config['token-secret'],{ expiresIn: config['token-expires']});
    let username = 'root_admin'
    let password = 'Admin123';
    let token = String(cryptojs.lib.WordArray.random(20));
    console.log("token : "+token);

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

      connection.query('SELECT * FROM users where username = ?  ',[username], async function(err, rows) { // await won't do anything here,
      // you should only use await with functions that return promises.
        if (err) {
          console.log("Looged out failed");
          throw new Error(err);
        } else {
          const user = rows[0];
          console.log("psdsdsd");
          if(bcrypt.compareSync(password,user.passwordHash)) {
            await connection.query('SELECT * FROM organizations where id = ?  ',[user.organizationId], async function(err, org_data) {
              if (err) {
                console.log("Looged out failed");
                throw new Error(err);
              } else {
                console.log("sdsd");
                //console.log(org_data);
                if(typeof org_data.name!='undefined') {
                  organization = org_data.name;
                } else {
                  organization = 'VeriCurious';
                }
                //console.log(organization);
                // create a token
                const token = await jwt.sign({ id: user.id, username: user.username, organizationId: user.organizationId, organization: organization}, config['token-secret'], {
                  expiresIn: config['token-expires'] // expires in 30 minutes
                }); 
                console.log("Successfull loggedin");
                console.log("New generated token : "+token);
                resolve(token); // this signals the Promise to resolve.
                // return token;
              }
            });
          }
        }    
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Some things to note:

1. Await is intended to work with promises. Asynchronous functions in javascript, either accept a callback or return a promise. `connection.query` takes a callback, so `await` is useless there.
2. Chances are that the module your using to talk to your database -mongoose?- has a promisified API. Check it out, because if you're willing to use async/await it is better to work directly with Promises rather than wrapping code in a new Promise.

For instance, if `connection.query` returned a Promise, you could do something like:

```
const login = async function () {
  // skipped a lot of code and logic since this is an example
    const rows = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM users where username = ?  ',[username]);
    const user = rows[0];
    const org_data = await  connection.query('SELECT * FROM organizations where id = ?  ',[user.organizationId]);
    const organization = org_data.name;

    return await jwt.sign({ id: user.id, username: user.username, organizationId: user.organizationId, organization: organization}, config['token-secret'], {
                expiresIn: config['token-expires'] // expires in 30 minutes
  });
}
```

And handling errors is really simple.

3. When you get an error un a callback inside an `async` function, and you're returning a new Promise -like in my example- I don't really know if is better to `reject` or to `throw` the error. I think both will do the same but I'm not sure.

Comment: Throwing in almost every case automatically rejects the promise for you. Virtually the only time it fails to reject is when the exception is caught inside the promise itself. Try / Catch is used inside Async functions to handle rejected promises ***and*** exceptions/errors. Alternatively `.catch()` method on promises also automatically catches exceptions that are thrown. IMO, I prefer to `throw` as it differentiates promises that are rejected due to non-error conditions (timeouts for instance)